# linux firewall rule - iptables –A INPUT rule that will accept any packet that comes in over ports 43,53 or 67

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I need an linux firewall rule that will accomplish the following:  iptables –A INPUT rule that will accept any packet that comes in over ports 43,53 or 67.

I am new to this.  Do you have to have -p "protocol" before --dport 43,53,67 or can you take out the -p "protocol" and just have the --dport 43,53,67.  How would you have accept any packet that could come over multiple protocols?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use it for all protocols you want to allow

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 43,53,67 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 43,53,67 -j ACCEPT
```

`--dport` is not a flag for general iptables rules. It's a flag for one of it's extended packet matching modules. These are loaded when you use `-p protocol` or `-m`. Unless you specify `-m <protocol> or -p <protocol>` with a specific protocol you can't use `--dport`

Comment: So there is not one command that will cover both udp and tcp, you have to have 2 separate commands?  e.g. -p tcp,udp,icmp or -p all?

Comment: can you just use iptables -A INPUT -m multiport --dports 43,53,67 -j ACCEPT to cover all protocols instead of defining each one?

Comment: In my knowledge, as I mentioned only one protocol in single command, because most of the other options depends on the matched protocol. for example TCP and UDP are using port numbers, but icmp not.